# MethodArgumentNotValidException not thrown

Tags: java, spring, validation

My controller looks like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars/{types}", method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void startEngine(
        @PathVariable @Min(0) String types, @RequestBody @Valid someObject request, BindingResult result)
        throws MethodArgumentNotValidException {

    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        //Should I be throwing MethodArgumentNotValidException here? And if so how? I don't know how to retrieve the first parameter for it's constructor (MethodParameter object)
    }
    //Controller code
}
```

So after I verify whether or not my result object encountered any errors during validation, how can I then throw the MethodArgumentNotValidException? Or should Spring be already throwing that exception during validation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Spring should throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException` **only** if you have not provided an `Errors` (here, `BindingResult`) parameter for the `@Valid` annotated parameter.

You can throw it yourself if you would like to.

Comment: @user1553248 Before you do, I'd check if what I say is true. I don't have a machine with Spring to test this on right now.

Comment: I have, I opted that removing the BindingResult object is actually a better solution to my problem, and now Spring is throwing MethodArgumentNotValidExceptions appropriately.

Comment: Do you know how to throw the MethodArgumentNotValidException? Retrieving the method parameter which correlates to the incorrect field is difficult.

Comment: @user1553248 Seeing that, you should probably throw a custom exception.

Comment: Still it is not working for me. I have extended ResponseEntityExceptionHandler in ControllerAdvice and there I have Override the method handleMethodArgumentNotValid. Here I want to return custom error message but it is not working. Default message structure is being thrown by Spring.

Comment: This worked well for me. The tutorials I used didn't specify to not use BindingResult. By simply removing them, my @ExceptionHandler would correctly intercept the exception and return my error text as a custom ResponseEntity.